# My RecyclerView has many rows but shows only one row?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

its  recyclerview inside recyclerview inside recyclerview 
it seems to be OK even the row is added but it doesn't show any thing.
many questions like this asked already and answered  but none solved mine

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/fn_file_field_card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      card_view:cardElevation="0dp">

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fn_field_margin_right_and_left"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fn_field_margin_top_or_bottom"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fn_field_margin_right_and_left"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ir.tenthwindow.lbs.views.PersianTextView
            android:id="@+id/fn_file_field_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="btn"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/fn_field_text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

         <ir.tenthwindow.lbs.views.PersianTextView
             android:id="@+id/fn_file_field_btn"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:background="@drawable/button_green"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:maxLines="1"
             android:padding="10dp"
             android:text="@string/upload_file"
             android:textColor="@color/white"
             android:textSize="@dimen/fn_field_text_size" />
           <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/fn_field_images_RecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

         <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fn_field_line_margin_top"
            android:background="@color/fn_grey_line_border">
         </View>
     </LinearLayout>
  </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Thx in advance for helping me

Comment: check your adapter xml file, set height to wrap content

Comment: that is correct
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change height of recyclerview to `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  android:id="@+id/fn_field_images_RecyclerView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

& height of layout in adapter to `wrap_content` if you set it as `match_parent`.

Also, set `LinearLayoutManager` to `Vertical` orientation.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you need a layout manager for recyclerview to work. This can be added in xml, or programatically. In xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  android:id="@+id/fn_field_images_RecyclerView"
  app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Or programatically:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
yourRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Please note, there is also a GridLayoutManager if you want a grid layout.